# How to render precompiled Handlebars template in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Handlebars directly:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile("<div>template source</div>");
var html = template();
```

But when using a precompiled template with Ember.js, this wont work:

```
var template = Ember.TEMPLATES["myTemplate"];
template(); // throws an error
```

Also if a template is compiled using `Handlebars.compile`, properties wont be readed properly from Ember objects since `get` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates compiled with the Ember compiler are hard to call in isolation.

Like normal Handlebars templates they are functions, but instead of doing string concatenation, they send their output to a `Ember.RenderBuffer` (calling `push`).

Mocking that object is not enough, since they also need a reference to a `Ember.View` (which normally calls them), and the property syntax `{{mustache}}` internally creates a `Ember._HandlebarsBoundView` (as stated in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember._HandlebarsBoundView.html).

A solution is to use the normal Handlebars compiler, and passing properties to the resulting function as a plain JS object.

Answer (score 1):

You render a template using `Em.Handlebars.compile('template stuff here')` (not Handlebars.compile) because Ember extends the Handlebars library to automatically use the `get()` method, per the [Ember.Handlebars docs here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; but how do you use the returned value from `Ember.Handlebars.compile`? Also in this case, i need to render this template as a plain HTML string without property observers and detached from the DOM.

Comment: Sadly this is no longer supported. Glimmer might be helpful: https://glimmerjs.com/